# load 20 headerpics without long loading time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the best and easiest way to load 20 header pictures (for a slideshow in the header area), alltogether having a size of more than 1 MB. My site takes such a looong time to load...?
Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [lazy-loading](http://engineering.slideshare.net/2011/03/faster-page-loads-with-image-lazy-loading/) your images. That is to defer the load of the images that will not appear on the page instantly. Assuming that you are using slideshow — only first 3-5 images could be loaded as usual, all other could be retrieved after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Load some of them. Say 3-5 - amount you need to display full header row.
Show them. After your is loaded - start loading others. One by one. And start animating your slideshow. This way you can show your site faster.
And optimize your fotos as much as possible. You don't need to print'em. You need to show them.